# Module federation of react app using react router dom in nextjs shell app. The child routes should also work for shell links

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, webpack-module-federation, module-federationnextjs-mfutils

I am trying to use "a react child app having react dom router" to be utilised in a nextjs shell application. I want those child routes to be available in nextjs shell links too, Can you please suggest how to achieve this.
Basically whatever route path provided in child should also work for shell links paths.